# PDO catch PDOException fails on construction

Tags: php, class, pdo

I've seen variations of this code all over the place, including many S.O. posts:

```
class db extends PDO {

    public function __construct( $dbconf ) {
        $options = array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => $dbconf['persist'] ? true : false
            );
        try {
            parent::__construct('mysql:host='. $dbconf['dbhost'] .';port=3306;dbname='. $dbconf['dbname'] .';' , $dbconf['dbuser'],
                $dbconf['dbpass'],
                $options);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->myerror( $e->getMessage() );
            // echo 'Connection failed ... '. $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    ...

    private function myerror( $error ) {
        echo 'Connection failed ... '. $error;
    }

}
```

The class is instantiated with `$db = new db( $config );`, and it works great if the connection is valid, but it seems `PDOException` doesn't actually work if the connection fails. The `catch` totally fails to execute the `$this->myerror(...)` function! Instead of the useful `$e->getMessage()` that says "Connection failed ... Access denied for user blah", I get a `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function myerror() on a non-object in /.../lib/pdo.class.php on line 16`.

If I comment out the first line in the catch and uncomment the `echo`, it works as expected, reporting the reason for the connection error. Why would the message be available in the catch but not in the simple `myerror` class function?

This post ... [PHP, PDO, and Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188167/php-pdo-and-exceptions) ... seems applicable, but doesn't explain much. Is `catch (PDOException $e)` obsolete, or dysfunctional under certain circumstances? How do I keep get this to work?

Comment: change it to `self::myerror()`

Comment: So the exception works, only your method call doesn't...!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being is `PDO::__construct` only creates the `object` upon successful connection. So when you call the parent constructor and it fails your object doesn't exist anymore. You should use `self::myerror()` to access the error function statically in this case.

Comment: Yep, you nailed it. Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be `myerror()` function at all. A database layer scarcely need it's own error handler.
And constructor have to be

```
public function __construct( $dbconf ) {
    $dsn  = "mysql:";
    $dsn .= "host=".   $dbconf['dbhost'].";";
    $dsn .= "dbname=". $dbconf['dbname'].";";
    $dsn .= "port=".   $dbconf['dbport'].";";
    $dsn .= "charset=".$dbconf['dbcharset'];
    $options = array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES '.$dbconf['charset'],
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT         => (bool)$dbconf['persist'],
    );
    parent::__construct($dsn, $dbconf['dbuser'], $dbconf['dbpass'],$options);
}
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this, but my example was grossly simplified. I have all sorts of session debugging tools in place that require a myerror() function :)

Comment: You should have it in exception handler, not in a database layer