# PHP call to parent's construct which try-catch kills $this

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I've a database class, which extends the PDO class.
I call the __construct function of the database class, to get a pdo instance.

```
// database.class.php
public function __construct($host, $port , $user, $password, $dbName) {
    $dsn = 'mysql:Host=' . $host . ';Port=' . $port . ';dbname=' .  $dbName;
    parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $password);
}
```

That works perfectly, but now I want to catch PDOExceptions.
I want to throw my DatabaseException which gets the current database instance as parameter, to gather peaces of information from it.
The problem is that the construct of my exception says that the parameter is not a DatabaseObject, it's just NULL.
Here an example:

```
// database.class.php
public function __construct($host, $port , $user, $password, $dbName) {
    $dsn = 'mysql:Host=' . $host . ';Port=' . $port . ';dbname=' .  $dbName;
    try {
        parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $password); // wrong credentials given
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        var_dump($this); // NULL
    }
    var_dump($this); // NULL
}
```

P.S.:
    var_dump(get_class($this));
gets:
lib\system\database\Database

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269247/pdo-catch-pdoexception-fails-on-construction

Comment: What I'd really recommend is using composition instead of inheritance here.

Comment: See the comment of rain. `$this` will only be succesful set when the constructor is executed for 100%

Comment: I dont't understand what you mean with composition, I've googled for it, but I don't get it.

Comment: Composition is `function __construct (PDO $pdo) { $this->pdo = $pdo; }`. It *composes* an object with other object instances, instead of `extend`ing them.